# What am I doing wrong here, and how do i do it right?

Tags: undefined, python-3.4, function

```
def movedamage:
    if Move=="Bop":
        MoveDamage=60
    if Move=="Bim":
        MoveDamage=60
    if Move=="Bam":
        MoveDamage=60
    if Move=="Pow":
        MoveDamage=60
print(Enemy)
print(Enemypokemon)
print ("A wild " + (Enemypokemon) + " has appeared")
print ("what would you like to do?")
molly=input ("1.Battle\n2.Switch pokemon")
if molly=="2":
    for pokemon in PokemonInventory:
        print (pokemon)
if molly=="1":
    Pokehealth=(operator.itemgetter(4)(Currentpokestats))
    Enemypokehealth=(operator.itemgetter(4)(Enemypokestats))
    print("Enemy pokemon health: "+ Enemypokehealth)
    print("Your pokemon health: "+ Pokehealth )
    Move=input ("Select move\n" +CurrentMoveset)


    EnemyHealth=operator.itemgetter(4)(Enemypokestats)
    Attack=operator.itemgetter(0)(Currentpokestats)
    Totaldamage=(int((int(Attack))*int((MoveDamage)))/60)
    Enemypokehealth=(int(Enemypokehealth))-Totaldamage
    print("Enemy pokemon health:" +str(Enemypokehealth))
    print("You did " + str(Totaldamage)+ " with " +(Move))
```

When I input either `Bop`, `Bim`, `Bam`, or `Pow`, I get an error:

```
"Totaldamage=(int((int(Attack))*int((MoveDamage)))/60)
NameError: name 'MoveDamage' is not defined"
```

This confuses me, as I thought that I had made it so that "MoveDamage" would be 60 if I used any of the previous inputs. However, I get this error with all of them.

Comment: Please give a more meaningful title. And add a tag for the language you are using.

Comment: Maybe the type of pokemon you're using "is not very effective" against the enemy pokemon... but seriously now, I dunno what language this is, but I'll  guess it's case sensitive and vote that the problem is that you defined `movedamage` and are using `MoveDamage`

Comment: Which programming language is this? At a quick guess, it looks like you define the movedamage function but you never call it after the Move input, so the MoveDamage variable does not get set. MoveDamage is only being set within the movedamage function (you probably want to rename the function so you do not get confused).

Comment: It looks like python to me

Comment: @Keilaron: The `def` tag is for Python questions, which is good enough for me

Answer (score 3):

`Move` is not defined within `movedamage`, and you never set `MoveDamage`. Instead, pass a parameter, and return a value.

```
def moveDamage(move):
    if move in ["Bop", "Bim", "Bam", "Pow"]:
        return 60
    else:
        return 0
```

Then use

```
moveDamage(Move)
```

Also, python is case sensitive, but that doesn't mean you should name your function `movedamage` and your variable `MoveDamage`. It makes the code confusing and unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

First, please add a python tag. Second, the reason that MoveDamage is not defined is that the indentation makes your function movedamage end after the if Move=="Pow" which means the later call to MoveDamage is out of scope.

I don't know how you were intending to call this but you should use something more like this:

```
def movedamage (move) :
    if move == "Bop" :
......

#then call with
damage = movedamage("Bop")`
```